# service destroys when clear multitasking stack android

Tags: android, service, background-process, multitasking, ondestroy

I am working with **services** in my android application but i have little problem using services that when i am closing my application from **Multitasking** then suddenly background **service** from that application stopped and even i don't get log from onDestroy of service...

I think it is killed because of android destroying all the resources of application and my service also killed.

after some time service autometically statring ... I don't know reason of that..

Is there any solution to make continuosly running my service ??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume close app from Multitasking equals killing the app process, which 
is what most process/task apps do.

I also assume you know your code does not contain some sort of an [Alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) 
that periodically wakes up to restart your service.

If the described behavior is consistent and happens within seconds after 
app close, we can probably also rule out a broadcast receiver that wakes 
up to start the thread.

Which leaves us with one last explanation: your process was declared to be [sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY):

```
class MyService extends Service { 

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
        return START_STICKY; // declare service to be sticky
    }

}
```

A sticky service is a service that asks Android to restart it after a sudden death, 
as long as the system resources allows for such a restart.

What you have describes perfectly fits sticky behavior. Removing the sticky flag 
should solve your problem.

Comment: ok thanks for answer..first let me know about sticky service and i'll be come back to the my problem again..

Comment: these all returned value gives options for restart or not service after killed...but my problem is actually i dont want to see service to be killed.....